# Header authorization best practice with Alamofire 4, with global 401 code catching

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm implementing authorization in my app in which I use Alamofire 4.0
I have a token to add to the header in each HTTP request I make, and I have to check in every request if the response code is 401, in that situation I have to logout the user.

What is the best practice? Is there an easy way to add this behaviour to each request?

I took a look at the session manager and request adapter [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md), and it was pretty easy to create a singleton request manager and use it to create the requests, but I can't find a nice way to add a centralized validation for the 401 response code.
This has to be a general validation, if it fails I log out the user, if it passes I would let handle the request to whoever made the request.

My desired goal is to have only one point in my code where I check for 401 error code.

I didn't find a satisfing answer looking around
Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, trying to solve the same problem, did you find a way to do it?

Comment: I overridden the session manager as suggested from the answer below. Then I did a basic validation for 401 code. If the validation passes then I call the completion handler of whoever made the request

Comment: @allemattio can you post some code of your solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple `GET` method in `SessionManager`. Create a separate class for webservice with validation in each request.

```
  let alamofireManager: SessionManager = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = AppConstants.maxSimultaneousDownloads
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    return SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
  }()


 self.alamofireManager.request(UrlString)
        .responseJSON { response in

          print("response: \(response)")

          guard response.result.isSuccess else {
          //Request fails here. Trigger here to log out the user
            return
          }

          if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("Successful")
            //or check response code here

          }
      }
```

Comment: I don't think this answer my question. What I really want is to centralize the 401 error handling, in all other cases I want to demand to whoever made the request to handle the success or other failure cases(422, 500, etc..). You are suggesting to handle the 401 in every request I make, I would like to avoid this. Edited my question to better explain my problem